# correct way to use mcelog on latest versions of Debian

Tags: mcelog

I found some documentation but it looks a bit outdated:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-server-predicting-hardware-failure.html

I see that I can specify a device as input but the documentation does not mention anything specific about that. How should I proceed if (for example) I want to detect if  there is a webcam problem?

Also is it a good idea to run mcelog at start with a systemd unit? if yes,  which options should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `mcelog` package sets up a daemon which translates MCEs into human-readable form and logs them to the system logs. You can then see them in `/var/log/syslog` or using `journalctl`. The daemon is started from an init script, there's no need to add a systemd unit for it.

It's unlikely the webcam issues you're seeing would trigger MCEs though, so I doubt this would help you. The device specified as input for `mcelog` isn't an input device, it's the special device used for communication between the kernel and anything interested in MCEs (`mcelog` in this case).

Answer (score 8):

`mcelog` was removed in Debian 10 (Buster). The functionality has been replaced by `rasdaemon`.